# Save updated XMLDocument as a string (vb.net or other .net lang.)

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XMl string in a Field of a mySQL Table. I load an XMLdocument (xmlDoc) from that string 
I then Search for a node and change an attribute. All good in here.

Then I want to save changes that i made to the XMLDocument in string format so i can update my table in the DB.
How can I do this.?

If I execute xmldoc.save(), well, it will save a XML file. How can I save the changes that I have made but instead of savig the file, save it as a string so I can save it in my table.

I really do not want to parse the XML string as a normal string to search my parameters and save it.

I am working on vb.net, but if you have code in other .net lang, no problem.
The DB is in MySQL

Comment: What is an XMLdoc? I've never heard of such a class.

Comment: What Andrew Cowenhoven post was what i was looking for, Thank you all for the quick response!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry it's C#, but you'll  get the idea. Do something like:

```
    XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
    dom.LoadXml("<test><cases><case id='2'>one</case></cases></test>");
    dom.SelectSingleNode("/test/cases/case[1]").Attributes["id"].InnerText = "1";
    string x = dom.OuterXml;
```

And then use x to update the database field.

Comment: Indeed, this is the answer. Thank you very much Andrew!